# Output the post taxonomy values in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

First of all I should say that I’m a beginner, I want to apologize for all the mistakes and my ignorance in coding.

I’m trying to create a **custom taxonomy and assign a value for each post**, I’d like to **output all the values** of the taxonomy and **mark the assigned one**.
The result should be something like this

[level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDTTS.png)

This is the code that I’ve tried to use

```
if (has_term( 'A1', 'levels' )) {
echo '<div class="level"><p class="level-title">level</p><p><mark>'?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'levels'); echo '</mark> A2 B1 B2 C1 C2</p></div>';
                    }else{echo "";}
                    if (has_term( 'A2', 'levels' )) {
                        echo '<div class="level"><p class="level-title">level</p><p>A1 <mark>'?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'levels'); echo '</mark> B1 B2 C1 C2</p></div>';
                    }else{echo "";}
                    if (has_term( 'B1', 'levels' )) {
                        echo '<div class="level"><p class="level-title">level</p><p>A1 A2 <mark>'?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'levels'); echo '</mark> B2 C1 C2</p></div>';
                    }else{echo "";}
                    if (has_term( 'B2', 'levels' )) {
                        echo '<div class="level"><p class="level-title">level</p><p>A1 A2 B1 <mark>'?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'levels'); echo '</mark> C1 C2</p></div>';
                    }else{echo "";}
                    if (has_term( 'C1', 'levels' )) {
                        echo '<div class="level"><p class="level-title">level</p><p>A1 A2 B1 B2 <mark>'?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'levels'); echo '</mark> C2</p></div>';
                    }else{echo "";}
                    if (has_term( 'C2', 'levels' )) {
                        echo '<div class="level"><p class="level-title">level</p><p>A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 <mark>'?> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'levels'); echo '</mark></p></div>';
                    }else{echo "";}
```

but it seems is not working appropriately, it returns the following messages:

> Notice: Undefined variable: level in /home/customer/www/englishwithfrancesca.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/home-template.php on line 169
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object in /home/customer/www/englishwithfrancesca.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/home-template.php on line 169

**I bet there’s a smarter way to code it.**

Thanks in advance for any help!